# How to extract filename from path

Tags: c

There should be something elegant in Linux API/POSIX to extract base file name from full path

Answer (score 63, accepted):

See [`char *basename(char *path)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/basename).

Or run the command "`man 3 basename`" on your target UNIX/POSIX system.

Answer (score 17):

Use `basename` (which has odd corner case semantics) or do it yourself by calling `strrchr(pathname, '/')` and treating the whole string as a basename if it does not contain a `'/'` character.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example of a one-liner (given `char * whoami`) which illustrates the basic algorithm:

```
(whoami = strrchr(argv[0], '/')) ? ++whoami : (whoami = argv[0]);
```

an additional check is needed if NULL is a possibility.  Also note that this just points into the original string -- a "`strdup()`" may be appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `strstr` in case you are interested in the directory names too:

```
char *path ="ab/cde/fg.out";
char *ssc;
int l = 0;
ssc = strstr(path, "/");
do{
    l = strlen(ssc) + 1;
    path = &path[strlen(path)-l+2];
    ssc = strstr(path, "/");
}while(ssc);
printf("%s\n", path);
```

Answer (score 4):

The `basename()` function returns the last component of a path, which could be a folder name and not a file name. There are two versions of the `basename()` function: the GNU version and the POSIX version.

The GNU version can be found in `string.h` after you include `#define _GNU_SOURCE`:

```
    #define _GNU_SOURCE

    #include <string.h>
```

The GNU version uses `const` and does not modify the argument.

```
    char * basename (const char *path)
```

This function is overridden by the XPG (POSIX) version if `libgen.h` is included.

```
    char * basename (char *path)
```

This function may modify the argument by removing trailing '/' bytes. The result may be different from the GNU version in this case:

```
    basename("foo/bar/")
```

will return the string "bar" if you use the XPG version and an empty string if you use the GNU version.

References:

  basename (3) - Linux Man Pages

  [Function: char * basename (const char *filename)](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html#index-basename)
  , Finding Tokens in a String.

Answer (score 3):

Of course if this is a Gnu/Linux only question then you could use the library functions.

https://linux.die.net/man/3/basename

And though some may disapprove these POSIX compliant Gnu Library functions do not use const. As library utility functions rarely do. If that is important to you I guess you will have to stick to your own functionality or maybe the following will be more to your taste?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *fn;
    char *input;

    if (argc > 1)
        input = argv[1];
    else
        input = argv[0];

    /* handle trailing '/' e.g. 
       input == "/home/me/myprogram/" */
    if (input[(strlen(input) - 1)] == '/')
        input[(strlen(input) - 1)] = '\0';

    (fn = strrchr(input, '/')) ? ++fn : (fn = input);


    printf("%s\n", fn);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
template<typename charType>
charType* getFileNameFromPath( charType* path )
{
    if( path == NULL )
        return NULL;

    charType * pFileName = path;
    for( charType * pCur = path; *pCur != '\0'; pCur++)
    {
        if( *pCur == '/' || *pCur == '\\' )
            pFileName = pCur+1;
    }
    
    return pFileName;
}
```

call:
wchar_t * fileName = getFileNameFromPath < wchar_t > ( filePath );

(this is a c++)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should note that this question was tagged [tag:c], while your answer is in [tag:c++]..

Answer (score 1):

You can escape slashes to backslash and use this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char path[] = "C:\\etc\\passwd.c"; //string with escaped slashes
  char temp[256]; //result here
  char *ch; //define this
  ch = strtok(path, "\\"); //first split
  while (ch != NULL) {
      strcpy(temp, ch);//copy result
      printf("%s\n", ch);
      ch = strtok(NULL, "\\");//next split
  }

  printf("last filename: %s", temp);//result filename

  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a simpler way to get just the filename or last part in a path.

```
char * extract_file_name(char *path)
{
    int len = strlen(path);
    int flag=0;
    printf("\nlength of %s : %d",path, len);

    
    for(int i=len-1; i>0; i--)
    {
        if(path[i]=='\\' || path[i]=='//' || path[i]=='/' )
        {
            flag=1;
            path = path+i+1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return path;
}
```

```
Input path = "C:/Users/me/Documents/somefile.txt"
Output = "somefile.txt"
```

Answer (score -2):

@Nikolay Khilyuk offers the best solution except.

1) Go back to using char *, there is absolutely no good reason for using const.

2) This code is not portable and is likely to fail on none POSIX systems where the / is not the file system delimiter depending on the compiler implementation. For some windows compilers you might want to test for '\' instead of '/'. You might even test for the system and set the delimiter based on the results.

The function name is long but descriptive, no problem there. There is no way to ever be sure that a function will return a filename, you can only be sure that it can if the function is coded correctly, which you achieved. Though if someone uses it on a string that is not a path obviously it will fail. I would have probably named it basename, as it would convey to many programmers what its purpose was. That is just my preference though based on my bias your name is fine. As far as the length of the string this function will handle and why anyone thought that would be a point? You will unlikely deal with a path name longer than what this function can handle on an ANSI C compiler. As size_t is defined as a unsigned long int which has a range of 0 to 4,294,967,295.

I proofed your function with the following.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    char* getFileNameFromPath(char* path);

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        char *fn;

        fn = getFileNameFromPath(argv[0]);
        printf("%s\n", fn);
        return 0;
    }

    char* getFileNameFromPath(char* path)
    {
       for(size_t i = strlen(path) - 1; i; i--)  
       {
            if (path[i] == '/')
            {
                return &path[i+1];
            }
        }
        return path;
    }
```

Worked great, though Daniel Kamil Kozar did find a 1 off error that I corrected above. The error would only show with a malformed absolute path but still the function should be able to handle bogus input. Do not listen to everyone that critiques you. Some people just like to have an opinion, even when it is not worth anything.

I do not like the strstr() solution as it will fail if filename is the same as a directory name in the path and yes that can and does happen especially on a POSIX system where executable files often do not have an extension, at least the first time which will mean you have to do multiple tests and searching the delimiter with strstr() is even more cumbersome as there is no way of knowing how many delimiters there might be. If you are wondering why a person would want the basename of an executable think busybox, egrep, fgrep etc...

<s>strrchar() would be cumbersome to implement as it searches for characters not strings so I do not find it nearly as viable or succinct as this solution.</s> I stand corrected by Rad Lexus this would not be as cumbersome as I thought as strrchar() has the side effect of returning the index of the string beyond the character found.

Take Care

Comment: I cannot agree with the sentence "Go back to using char *, there is absolutely no good reason for using const.". There is absolutely a very good reason for using const : why would you even modify the string passed into this function anyway? `const` is a crucial part of the interface declaration : I don't think you want to tell the caller of the function "I will return the basename, but I might also put some random bytes at a position that I like". Also, this is an infinite loop, since `size_t` is always `>= 0`.

Comment: ".. strrchar()" (*sic*) "... would be cumbersome to implement as it searches for characters not strings .." and yet you are searching for a single character. A fact, not an opinion.

Comment: @Rad Lexus, you are looking for the string beyond the last delimiter so yes it would require more testing and that is a fact not an opinion. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Daniel Kamil Kozar

No it is not an infinite loop it tests the value of i, not the value of size_t and I is decremented by the prefix operator in the third expression of the for loop, why can you not see that? 

I tested the code I posted and it works.

The issue with your interface theory is that we are likely to be passing char * (strings) returned by other functions, as in the argv example and they would have to be copied to a const char * or casted to work with your interface ideology. And it is not warranted.

Comment: I'm afraid you did not quite get the intention of that remark by LSerni. The *entire function and reference* to `getFileNameFromPath (..)` can be removed in its entirety and replaced with `fn = strrchr(argv[0], '/');`. With, if required, an additional test for `fn = NULL`, in which case it does `fn = argv[0]`.

Comment: @JamieRRobillardSr. - `i` is of type `size_t`, and it is by definition unsigned. Thus the function will never return if the string doesn't contain a `/`. And you can pass a `char*` into a function which takes a `const char*` just fine, without making any copies in between.

Comment: @Rad Lexus The point I am trying to get at is that even with a strrchar() in a reverse search looking for the delimiter you are encumbering function with a marco that could just as easily and clearly been implemented with a simple comparison expression. Providing of course that your implementation of C uses a macro (as most ansi c compilers do) and not an actual function, which of course would be even more costly.

Comment: @Daniel Kamil Kozar and there is no reason a utility function needs to be treated as an interface. There is no reason for either the argument or the return value to be immutable.

Comment: @JamieRRobillardSr. : as much as I'm not a fan of proving the presence of undefined behaviour by inspecting the assembly output, I think it is the only remaining way to convince you. Have a look at [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/3J0BGS) using gcc 6.3 to compile your code, and the label `.L5` : `rdx` is decremented without being checked for zero at all, which means that it will be "decremented" to `SIZE_MAX` (2^64 - 1 in this particular case) if no `/` is present before `i` reaches zero. This means that you will access `path` with a negative index, which is UB.

Comment: @JamieRRobillardSr., for what value of i will the for loop break?

Comment: @JamieRRobillardSr. : I think that settles it. Thanks.

Comment: @JamieRRobillardSr., While I recognize the terse tension here, I really am missing something.  If the loop "will break for 0", as you said, the condition reads ">= 0", so for i == 0, the condition is still true, and execution continues at least one more time.  If you see what I'm missing, please explain.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar as it turns out this is a 1 off error and it does create a bug that would not likely be found running on real data. As even a absolute path at root of the directory system (/) will parse as /<filename so the '/' would be there. Though of course the for loop not being able to exit on its condition because of the bounds issue is definitely a bug.

And though it may sound like I am talking around it the fact is you are right, it was buggy, you where just wrong about what the bug was <continued>

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar I did not understand your wording and the loop always exited so that is why I kept debating the issue. 

You are right a size_t (because it is unsigned) cannot be less than zero. As it turns out 0 was the thresh hold anyway and testing beyond it was a one off error. Which was the real bug in the first place.

Take care!

Comment: @donjuedo yes the for i == 0 would be true and that was the issue. The loop should be terminating at 0. I fixed the bug above.

Comment: @RadLexus good point, I missed that ;). thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score -3):

My example (improved):

```
    #include <string.h>

    const char* getFileNameFromPath(const char* path, char separator = '/')
    {
        if(path != nullptr)
        {
            for(size_t i = strlen(path);  i > 0; --i)
            {
                if (path[i-1] == separator)
                {
                    return &path[i];
                }
            }
        }
    
        return path;
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't handle very long strings; should probably take a `const char *`, not a `char *`; misleading name (result is not guaranteed to be a file).

Comment: @melpomene: many thanks for the review, the function was adapted. But according to a naming remark, I guess you should additionally check if a given path is file or not in case if it is needed.

Comment: What about `strrchr()`?

Comment: This is an infinite loop, since `size_t` is always `>= 0`.

Comment: @Jamie R Robillard Sr.: Thanks for constructive comments and thoughts!